# Creating nav menu with nested content_tag ULs and LIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a relative newbie to Rails, but wondering how to create a looping nav menu using content_tag. This should seemingly work, but I've seen that one must use concat inside of a content_tag loop. I feel that I've tried every possible avenue and and googled heartily. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

FYI:

- I pass @page.root to the right_nav function in my view in order to display the full branch from whatever section I may be in.
- for_menu checks to see whether a given page is supposed to be displayed in the menu.

Thanks.

```
  def right_nav(page)
    content_tag(:ul, :class => 'nav') do
      if !page.children.for_menu.empty?
        sub_nav(page)
      else
        concat content_tag(:li, link_to(page.title, page.path, :class=> current_menu_item?(page) ? 'current' : nil))
      end
    end
  end

  def sub_nav(parent)
    content_tag(:li, nav_link(parent)) do
      content_tag(:ul) do
        parent.children.for_menu.each do |subpage|
          if !subpage.children.for_menu.empty?
            sub_nav(subpage)
          else
            content_tag(:li, nav_link(subpage))
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def nav_link(page)
    link_to(page.title, page.path)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using each, maybe try using collect in your loop; that way the results are passed back up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

The inner content_tag :ul is not getting a proper return value from each since each returns the collection that it was called on.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > [1,2,3,4].each {|n| n + 1}
 => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

For something like content_tag you can use inject which will concat together all the li/sub_nav items and return that to the content_tag properly

```
def sub_nav(parent)
  content_tag(:li, nav_link(parent)) do
    content_tag(:ul) do
      parent.children.for_menu.inject('') do |result, subpage|
        if !subpage.children.for_menu.empty?
          result + sub_nav(subpage)
        else
          result + content_tag(:li, nav_link(subpage))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```